# AngularJS - ng-repeat show header just once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 lists (`persons` and `animals`) that I'm displaying with `ng-repeat`. I want to show these two lists in one table with a heading.
Here is an example how I want to show the data.
I already tried it with `ng-show="$first"`, but that is not the result I want to achieve.

[image]

```html
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>BIRTHDAY</th>
  <th>NAME</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="ps in $ctrl.persons" ng-if="$ctrl.valuePersons == true">
  <th ng-show="$first">PERSONS</th>
   <td>{{ ps.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ ps.birthday | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
   <td>{{ ps.name }}</td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr ng-repeat="an in $ctrl.animals" ng-if="$ctrl.valueAnimals == true">
  <th ng-show="$first">ANIMALS</th>
   <td>{{ an.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ an.birthday | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
   <td>{{ an.name }}</td>
 </tr>
<tbody>
```

Comment: Hi what was the result with `$first`?

Comment: The first row looks like: PERSONS | 1 | 12.05.2010 | Lisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, as per the documentation for [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat%20ng-repeat).

```
...
<tr ng-repeat-start="ps in $ctrl.persons" ng-if="$ctrl.valuePersons == true && $first">
    <th>PERSONS</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="$ctrl.valuePersons == true && !$first">
    <td>{{ ps.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ ps.birthday | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{ ps.name }}</td>
</tr>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is long but can help you...

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>BirthDay</th>
   <th>NAME</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Persons</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="ps in $ctrl.persons">
     <td>{{ps.id}}<td/>
     <td>{{ps.bday}}<td/>
     <td>{{ps.name}}<td/>
   </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Animals</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="ps in $ctrl.animals">
     <td>{{ps.id}}<td/>
     <td>{{ps.bday}}<td/>
     <td>{{ps.name}}<td/>
   </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I'm a fan of using `colspan="2"` in place of repeating blank `td` elements, especially when the row is meant to separate two sections of a table. `<td colspan="2">Persons</td>`. Certainly a stylistic choice, but one that makes both the HTML and the resulting table look cleaner.

Comment: Yaa.. view and style you can choose what you like more :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("Profile", [] );
                app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope) {
                        $scope.items    = [{'title':'PERSON','data':[{'birth_day':'1/1/2011','name':'a1'},{'birth_day':'1/1/2011','name':'a2'},{'birth_day':'1/1/2011','name':'a3'}]},{'title':'ANIMALS','data':[{'birth_day':'1/1/2011','name':'a1'},{'birth_day':'1/1/2011','name':'a2'},{'birth_day':'1/1/2011','name':'a3'}]}]
                })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Profile" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
                <table class="table" border="1">
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>BIRTHDAY</th>
                                        <th>Name</thu>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-init="main_ind= $index">
                                        <td  colspan="3">{{item['title']}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="val in item['data']">
                                        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                        <td>{{val['birth_day']}}</td>
                                        <td>{{val['name']}}</td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
        </body>
```